# Why can't you steal the synchroniser token to do CSRF?

Tags: http, javascript, csrf

I'm reading up on CSRF and I came across synchroniser tokens. I don't understand why you can't do a CSRF to get the token to do a real CSRF.

Example: `bank.com` has a form like this at `https://bank.com/transfer`:

```
<form action="https://bank.com/do_transfer" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="synchroniser_token" value="j/DcoJ2VZvr7vdf8CHKsvjdlDbmiizaOb5B8DMALg6s=" >
  <input type="hidden" name="to"                 value="ciro">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount"             value="100">
  <button type="submit">Send 100$ to Ciro.</button>
</form>
```

*<sub>This code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26895980/1512962</sub>*

What would stop `malicioussite.com` from GETing `https://bank.com/transfer` with JavaScript on the client (using the session ID already stored in the cookie) and scrapping the page for the `authenticity_token`? Then, they could use that ID to do a *real* CSRF, essentially a CSRF to do another CSRF.

It'd require JavaScript to execute, so it'd be harder to do then a simple 0px X 0px image, but it's more than doable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What stops a malicious site from obtaining the anti-CSRF token is the Same Origin Policy. The Same Origin Policy, or SOP, is at the browser level, and defines where JavaScript is allowed to communicate.

JavaScript on `example.com` cannot call `example.org` to get data. Also, JavaScript on `http://www.example.com/` cannot call `http://www.example.com:8080/` as the port differs. There are further restrictions which are set and can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy.

There are exceptions to this with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, but that has its own rules that browsers have to follow. CORS can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: Beat me to it! Nicely written.

Comment: Unless the person has an extention that allows executing code on the same page, and that can scrap the document for the token. That way, it can still take the token and send the token as a fake GET request of an image. For example: `http://malicious/images/<token>.gif`. On the server, you can then receive it and do as you please.